# Can't start Acrylic DNS Proxy on my Windows machine

Tags: windows, dns, proxy

When installing the [*Acrylic DNS Proxy*](https://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome) on my Windows 10 Pro machine, I get this error:

```
2019-03-05 12:44:45.527 THostsCache.LoadFromFile: Done loading hosts cache items.
2019-03-05 12:44:45.528 TBootstrapper.StartSystem: Done loading hosts cache items.
2019-03-05 12:44:45.528 TBootstrapper.StartSystem: Starting DNS resolver...
2019-03-05 12:44:45.529 TBootstrapper.StartSystem: Done starting DNS resolver.
2019-03-05 12:44:45.531 TDnsResolver.Execute: TDualUdpCommunicationChannel.Bind: Binding to IPv4 address 0.0.0.0 and port 53 failed with Windows Sockets error code 10048.
```

To find out which process is blocking that port, I ran this command:

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetUDPEndpoint -LocalPort 53).OwningProcess
```

To which, I get this response:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    214      15     2632       6800              8620   0 svchost
```

How do I find out which program is *actually* using up the DNS port (53)? Or is there a Windows setting somewhere which needs to be turned on or off?

The thing is, Acylic used to run just find till a month or two ago.

> Some background: I was running a web-server in docker container, and had exposed the port 80 from the docker container to my PC's network. I had set the DNS for my PC's network to point to 127.0.0.1, which acrylic requires. Recently, I moved to WSL (Windows subsystem for linux), and thus didn't need the docker container, so I unexposed the ports (using the `netsh interface portproxy`) commands.

And that's when I *suspect* acrylic stopped working.

I can't reset my system that far back in the past to find out, but if there is anything anyone can tell me, I'd be very grateful. Feel free to ask for any more info if you need.

It's a flabbergasting situation `>:-[`

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) service had started on my computer somehow. This service had blocked the port 53 from being allotted to Acrylic.

Since I posted the question above, I couldn't find any Powershell command which would let me find the process consuming the port. But then I cross-referenced the PID number returned from this command:

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetUDPEndpoint -LocalPort 53).OwningProcess
```

and viewed the list of services in my Task Manager, and it turns out that it was the **ICS** service. I just stopped the service, *et voilà!*

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Thanks for pointing in the right direction.